# Invalid key for linkedin

Tags: npm, angular6, linkedin-api

I m using third party login with LinkedIn in my angular app. i use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-social-login-v2) npm package for social login using angular. Social login is working fine with `Google and Facebook` but unable to login with `LinkedIn`

What is try give the `Client Id` as per npm link(as mention above) documentation and i am getting  [image: this] error every time.

i did some research on it but unable to find any answer, any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

this issue is solved by installing
npm i angularx-social-login